# KeyError: 'acc' -> acc = history.history['acc']

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

link of the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_a4PLwDiFhF7qVlX_vvwKM4QM4Dxu0L0?usp=sharing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)

# "bo" is for "blue dot"
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
# b is for "solid blue line"
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Error shows:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-31-12e4df2349dc> in <module>
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 
----> 3 acc = history.history['acc']
      4 val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
      5 loss = history.history['loss']

KeyError: 'acc'
```

Hi I ve tried this exercise 3.5-classifying-movie-reviews.ipynb from deep learning with python -manning and shows error, any help please?

Comment: Second try: now is showing a graphic but still error: val_accuracy i added  plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])

Comment: You tried to log the entries of history? print(history.history.keys())

Answer (score 0):

Sample: Roughly plot graph, working to present required more time this only 15 epochs using a few simple dense layers on MNST database.

History is the dictionary you added as an array or training it creates as logging results, please use the model.fit() or callback method before conditions.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
RANDOM_STATE = 21
BATCH_SIZE = 16
EPOCHES = 15

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', shuffle_files=True)
ds = ds.shuffle(1024).batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
assert isinstance(ds, tf.data.Dataset)

for example in ds.take(1):
  image, label = example["image"], example["label"]

list_image = [ ]    
list_label = [ ]

list_image = tf.constant(image, shape=(64, 28, 28)).numpy()
list_label = tf.constant(label, shape=(64, 1, 1)).numpy()


samples=image.shape[0]

y_train = tf.random.uniform((samples, 1, 1), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ ])
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.18))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.15))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5) 

# Compiling the model
model.compile(loss='bce', optimizer='adam', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

# Fitting the model
history = model.fit(list_image, y_train, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, validation_data =(list_image, y_train), epochs = EPOCHES, callbacks=[es]) # verbose = 0

# Check out our train loss and test loss over epochs.
train_loss = history.history['loss']
test_loss = history.history['val_loss']
y_train = tf.constant(y_train, shape=(64, )).numpy()


print( test_loss )
print( y_train )



# Visualizing our training and testing loss by epoch
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(train_loss, label='Training Loss', color='#185fad')
plt.plot(test_loss, label='Testing Loss', color='orange')
# plt.plot(y_train, label='y_train', color='blue')
plt.title('Training and Testing Loss by Epoch', fontsize = 20)
# plt.title('label input', fontsize = 20)
plt.xlabel('Epoch', fontsize = 11)
plt.xlabel('n', fontsize = 11)
plt.ylabel('Binary Crossentropy', fontsize = 11)
plt.legend(fontsize = 11)

plt.show()

input('...')
```

Output:
[image: Sample]